# Type <list> in a csv file but when i take it becomes strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have csv file one of his rows is a list of comments when i read the csv file and take that row to work with it i found him string .
my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('sementique\comments_reddit_improved.csv')
# for exemple 
# print(df['comments'][0])
```

the result would be something like this
"['good work','not bad at all','i dont like that']"
the type of it is string not list
so i have tried this and didnt work

```
string="'"
table=[]  
start=0
end=0              
s=''
l=list(df['comments'][3])
for i in range(len(l)):
   if l[i]==string and l[i+1]==',':
       end==i
       continue
   if l[i]==string:
       start==i+1
   if start!=0 and end!=0:
      for j in range(start,end):
          s=s+l[j]
      table.append(s)
      start=0
      end=0
```

the variable table would be empty

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: `l[i]==string and l[i+1]==','`  will not gonna true because `l[i+1]==','` will return 0 always as list elements are separated by ',' which i thing you have misunderstood so **end** always remains 0 that's why tables remains empty

Comment: ty @AbhishekKumar for taking the time to respond thank you